# Защита от ддос атак PC

Tags: защита, ddos

Порты можно сказать все закрыты, но каким-то образом школьник досит и полностью инет пропадает, хотя сетевуха 1гб (100мб).

Можно ли как то защититься самому? Покупать защищенный IP 7крублей в месяц тупо...

Comment: много ниезвестных:

- это локальная машина или сервер
- какая операционка
- есть ли антивирусы/фаерволы
- прямое подключение или через роутер (серию роутеров)
- злоумышленник находиться в одной сети или его положение неизвестно

Comment: У вас же назгулы, вам все поперек! А вообще, Wireshark и смотрите чего там к вам прилетает.

Comment: Файвол comodo стоит.

Comment: Эм, у Вас 1ГБ = 100МБ??

Comment: @AivanF Это у него вход/выход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете хоть все позакрывать, но это не избавит Вас от случая, когда попросту забивают Ваш канал. А забить канал можно с любого нормального VPS/VDS простыми программами для "тестирования" сети. Что делать в таком случае?

Расширить свой канал, чтобы он был больше канала атакующего.

Comment: Канал раширенный на 1гб.

Comment: @Sauron Тогда ответьте на вопросы KoVadim. Потому что непонятно тогда у Вас сетевая карта на 1гб или канал? Откуда Вас вообще атакуют: из интернета или из локальной сети?